# c++ order range with values that doesn't fulfill strict weak ordering

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to order values in a range so the range represent a *chain*.

```
struct Link
{
   int id;
   int next;
};
```

The values of `Link::id` and `Link::next` are arbitrary, and do not provide any semantic meaning by them selves (not for the ordering algorithm any way).

The relationship between two links (after ordering) is: `lhs.next` is exactly `rhs.id`.

**preconditions**

- The unordered `range` is guaranteed to hold values that can be ordered into exactly one *chain*.
- It's guaranteed to be no recursion in the set of values (no loops)

**Example:**

```
std::vector< Link> range{ { 4, 1}, { 1, 5}, { 3, 4}, { 2, 3}};
auto chain = some_algorithm( range);
// expect the ordering to be: { { 2, 3}, { 3, 4}, { 4, 1}, { 1, 5}};
```

I can think of at least two approaches, but I suspect this has been *solved* in an idiomatic way. So, my question is: how to solve this in an idiomatic way?

Comment: There are values for which `some_algorithm` has multiple solutions. How would you cope with, for instance, `{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you expect if, rather than `2,3` that element were `5,3` ? In other words, wouldn't introducing a "loop", leave you with four possible sequences, all of which are correct (in that they fulfill your "chain" ? That alone suggests the restrictions of sorting algorithms (you *must* have a strict-weak ordering) in the standard library are not going to help you out here.

Comment: I'll update with preconditions. It's guaranteed to be no recursion in the value-set, and no  "hops"/multiple chains.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I know the standard algorithms demands _strict-weak-ordering_ (for a good reason), that's why I'm asking this question :)

Comment: @Paul Floyd, thank you.

Comment: Look at [Topological_sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

The "concept" R is some type that that behaves *range-like*, could be a container, could be something else.

If there are gaps (link-wise) in the `range`, new chains will be ordered. I didn't want to have some "assert-output", or throwing. I still maintain my goals, since in my use-case I know all values can form exactly one chain.

```
  template< typename R, typename ISP>
  R chain( R range, ISP is_link_predicate)
  {
     auto first = std::begin( range);
     auto current = first;
     const auto last = std::end( range);

     while( current != last)
     {
        const auto next = current + 1;

        // try to find a value in [next, last) that can be linked with *current.
        auto link = std::find_if( next, last, [current,is_link_predicate]( auto& value){
           return is_link_predicate( *current, value);
        });

        if( link != last)
        {
           using std::swap;
           swap( *next, *link);
           current = next;
        }
        else
        {
           // we need to check if some value in [next, last) can be "inserted" in the
           // beginning of the chain. That is, can form a link with *first.
           auto new_first = std::find_if( next, last, [first,is_link_predicate]( auto& value){
              return is_link_predicate( value, *first);
           });

           if( new_first != last)
           {
              // we got a new_first, we need to rotate it first
              //
              // C = current
              // N = next (not ordered).
              // - = ordered values
              // = = not ordered values
              // X = value to be "inserted" first, new_first
              //
              // -----CN====X===  we start with
              // X-----C========  we end up with
              //
              std::rotate( first, new_first, new_first + 1);
              current = next;
           }
           else
           {
              // no values in [next, last) is part of the current chain.
              // we start building the next chain.
              current = next;
              first = current;
           }
        }
     }

     return range;
  }
```

Comments?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have bothered in trying to solve this in place. I would copy the links to a new range while first looking for a start of a chain and chaining from there until a new chain is needed. However, that doesn't mean my approach would be better, just more familiar to me. I would also have needed to invalidate copied links.

Comment: I was hoping to get some suggestions on improving the algorithm. Either to few finds this interesting or the algorithm is good enough. I'll mark this as the solution since it's working pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that there is a idiomatic way because this isn't a common case.

Chaining is mostly done by pointers/iterators (e.g. `std::list`) and the actual chaining is mostly done while inserting.

The interesting thing would be to find the first link and what to do with circular chaining and with error cases.

Comment: I agree.  I would build an `unordered_map<int, Link>` which maps an int to the Link with that id, and another which maps an int to the Link with that `next`.  Then I would search all the Link's for the Link whose `id` is not a key in the `next` map - this is the first entry.  Finally, having found the first entry, one just repeatedly finds the next entry by looking up `next` in the `id` map.  Each individual operation is no worse than O(n log n), so the overall performance will be too (and it *might* be better than that).

Comment: I don't either think this is the common case. But, to me, it seams that this problem is not that far fetched, and someone, hopefully smarter than me, have given a lot of thoughts to this, hence my question :)